# When deploy app on Heroku, how to save images which I upload, on my PC file system?

Tags: heroku

When i want to upload file like image from my deployed app on Heroku it breaks process and gives me error.And I found this https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted.
If anyone know how to save files on my PC file system from Heroku deployed app,
please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that - your Heroku app will not have access to your PC to store files. You need to follow Heroku's guidance in the article that you've referenced.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Regards!